# Number of expermients(tosses) to check if coin is biased

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading questions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adobe-interview-set-13-campus-internship/). Then I read this question asked in interview:
How would you determine if a coin is biased or not. Does the degree of biasity effect the number of experiments you have to perform? (Example: if the prob of heads is 0.6 in one case and 0.7 in another, then would you still perform the same number of experiments to decide if they are biased or different number of experiments)

So, I know that we can make a better estimate of coin bias by doing more experiments. This will certainly give a better estimate of coin bias. But I am not sure about the second part of the question. That do we need to do same(large) number of experiments in all cases?
Any ideas about the second part of the question?

Comment: Standard deviation is a function of $p$ and $n$. For the same number of experiment, standard deviation get bigger as $p$ approach $0.5$. If you want the same confidence interval, you need more experiment for $p=0.6$ compared to $p=0.7$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is "hypothesis testing". In hypothesis testing, you have a null hypothesis (the coin is unbaised) and then you conduct experiments (flipping the coin repeatedly and recording the results) and then you can compute a value representing how certain you are that a coin is biased (more precisely, you compute the probability that rejecting the null hypothesis is incorrect).

Comment: For the second part of the question, I think the answer is no in general. Suppose your coin is super biased, say it always comes up heads. If you flip it $n$ times, you will obtain $n$ heads. And you know that this is super unlikely to happen if the coin was unbiased (in which case it happens with probability $1 / 2^n)$. So with a small number of trials, you can conclude with high certainty that the coin is biased.

Comment: So, roughly speaking, the greater the bias of coin, the lesser experiments we need to perform, right?